# Is it possible to use a MuleClient to send/dispatch a message directly to a flow without a specific inbound endpoint?

Tags: mule

I have a flow that I usually reference elsewhere with just a flow-ref component.  I would like to test this flow by making a call directly to it with a MuleClient.  Is this possible?  If so, can you provide an example.  Here's what I have, but it doesn't work.  Obviously, it's missing the protocol that would go before 'processChanges', but I don't know what that would be in this case.

```
MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
client.dispatch("processChanges", payload, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running from a [FunctionalTestCase](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/tests/functional/src/main/java/org/mule/tck/junit4/FunctionalTestCase.java) you can use the method `runFlow(String flowName, MuleEvent event)` to execute the flow with that `MuleEvent` as input. HTH.